# Update column from other table column with relation

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables

```
sale_order_line

id| order_id| date_order
1 | 5       |  null
2 | 6       | null
3 | 6       | null
```

and

```
sale_oder

id| date_order
5 | '2020-08-25'
6 | '2020-09-28'
```

How can I  construct query that will update all `date_order` in the `sale_order_line` table based on `order_id`

Desired output would be

```
id| order_id| date_order
1 | 5       | '2020-08-25'
2 | 6       | '2020-09-28'
3 | 6       | '2020-09-28'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) you can use a FROM clause in the UPDATE statement:

```
update sale_order_line sol
   set date_order = so.date_order
from sale_order so
where so.id = sol.order_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides using Postgres' update join syntax, you could also use a correlated subquery here:

```
UPDATE sale_order_line sol
SET date_order = (SELECT so.date_order FROM sale_order so WHERE so.id = sol.order_id);
```